# Google Play Game Services not working... Is OAuth consent screen necessary?

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-games, google-play-console

I'm trying to make work Google Play Game Services with a game, but it's displaying an error when trying to login with a signed release APK. I checked that the project id and the SHA-1 are correct.

The only important thing i missed is this:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling

6. At release, publish the Play Games services settings first before you publish your game
   Developers might accidentally publish their app without publishing the corresponding Google Play games services settings for their app. This might cause players who are signing in with non-tester accounts to encounter errors since the app cannot reference the correct game settings. **When releasing your game, remember to first publish your game settings by using the Publish Game option in the Google Play Console**.

I published first the aplication, and after that I published the game settings...

And also, I disscovered that "OAuth consent screen" is not done. It's empty. It's asking me to select  internal or external.

Is that the problem? Should I fill "OAuth consent screen" to make google play game services work?

Answer (score 4):

Well, finaly, I filed the Oauth consent screen and it starting working...

That should be done automatically or at least they should put this on the documentation, and it's not.

Comment: Work for me too! More info for my case: 
1. Choose 'External'
2. Leave icon as empty otherwise it says verification required
3. Not adding any more scope (only the 3 default ones)
4. Click 'Save'. Even the verification status says 'Not published' but GPGS starts working.

Comment: Wow, this worked. The first time I did the setup for GPG I didn't have to do that (I don't know if it was done automatically or something). However, I had to recreate the game project linked to the same app project in Play Console and the new setup was not working until I configured the consent screen (minimally, as per zevoid's suggested steps). Thanks!

Comment: @zevoid would you be able to tell us what are the 3 default scopes ?